# Is sonar-project.properties file only for SonarQube Runner?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I've been asked to get SonarQube up and running, but we'll be using maven instead of SonarQube Runner.

Is the sonar-project.properties configuration file only used for analysis with SonarQube Runner, or is it necessary for other analyzers, such as maven?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is only for SonarQube Runner. If you want to pass extra properties to maven you have to pass it on command line with `-D` prefix. Example: `mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.language=java`.

Answer (score 0):

In case of C# analysis also you need to add '-D' prefix. --

Something like this.

```
-Dsonar.language=cs 
-Dsonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file="EventProcessing.sln" 
-Dsonar.gendarme.mode= 
-Dsonar.gallio.coverage.tool=OpenCover 
-Dsonar.dotnet.visualstudio.testProjectPattern=*.Tests*
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as has been said, it is only for Sonar Runner because in this file you define your Project Name, Project Version, default locale from the source code of your Project and so on...

And in your case, using maven, the information like Project Name, Project Version and all about Project is defined in the pom.xml from your Project, and in the Maven you followed a folder structure and so you don't need to tell the source code locale.